# Download in .zip file works with website image but not image from Amazon S3 with signed Url

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I have an object with signed Urls to images on Amazon S3. My example is simplified to one image and my goal is to download a zip file with that image.

This image works with my code in the variable `$fileUrl`

> http://google.com/images/logo.png

But not this (in variable `$fileUrl`), I get a corrupt .zip file. I can open the image in the browser with the signed url.

> https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/94c70e8a-61f6-4f58-a4b7-1679df5a7c1f.jpg?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D94c70e8a-61f6-4f58-a4b7-1679df5a7c1f.jpg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNY3GPOFFLQ&Expires=1426371544&Signature=HDNhGKHDsjEgqkMreN3tbozkfzo%3D

```
  $zipName = 'zipfile.zip';

  # create new zip opbject
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  $fileUrl = 'https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/94c70e8a-61f6-4f58-a4b7-1679df5a7c1f.jpg?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D94c70e8a-61f6-4f58-a4b7-1679df5a7c1f.jpg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNY3GPOFFLQ&Expires=1426371544&Signature=HDNhGKHDsjEgqkMreN3tbozkfzo%3D';

  # create a temp file & open it
  $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
  $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($fileUrl);

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($fileUrl),$download_file);

    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp_file));
    readfile($tmp_file);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing the same behavior with zip/video files. I can download them directly from S3 just fine but when I use the AWS PHP SDK to get them they come back corrupt and only a fraction of their actual size.  

Even stranger - they worked perfectly for a time and then started failing.

Comment: Yes, can not remember exactly what it was but it was something that I sent wrong headers (# send the file to the browser as a download).

Comment: Cool, I will dig deeper into how we are manipulating headers and see if I can't find something that jumps out.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried so many combinations and having the same issue on Node.js. PDFs upload fine but all my images get corrupted